# Cannot delete by backspace in masked phone number

Tags: javascript, html, css, regex

I am trying to mask a phone number as follows:

(123) 131-5135- (x1345).

Where "1345" is the extension. But I am not able to delete the extension by backspace key. I have to select the extension and then delete it. The code is as follows:

```
<input type="text" id="aphonen" class="form-control" value="" />

<script>
    document.getElementById('aphonen').addEventListener('input', function (e) {
       var a = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})(\d{0,4})/);
       e.target.value = !a[2] ? a[1] : '(' + a[1] + ') ' + a[2] + (a[3] ? '-' + a[3] : '') + (a[4] ? '- (x' + a[4] +')' : '');
    });
</script>
```

Why is the backspace not working?

Comment: This is odd, if you move into the brackets and then delete (assuming you mean the extension at the end) then you can delete everything. It's just the bracket itself.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you have to check which key was pressed, if its not backspace only then run your code, below is the snippet:

```js
 var code;

       
      
         document.getElementById('aphonen').addEventListener('input', function (e) {
         if(code !== 8){
           var a = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})(\d{0,4})/);
           e.target.value = !a[2] ? a[1] : '(' + a[1] + ') ' + a[2] + (a[3] ? '-' + a[3] : '') + (a[4] ? '- (x' + a[4] +')' : '');
         }
      });
       

         

window.onkeydown = function (e) {
    code = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
//     console.log(code);
};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="aphonen" class="form-control" value="" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. However the issue with this is that when we start deleting unmasking does not happen automatically. I mean we have to delete the brackets also, "x" also "-" also and so on. They don't get removed automatically.

Comment: @ShubhamGoyal So how did you solve this issue finally? Meet the same issue.